# iBeacon Bluetooth didEnterRegion and didExitRegion methods are never fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

It's very strange that `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` are never fired after `startMonitoringForRegion` is called. In addition, `didDetermineState` could be triggered as expectation.

During the current stage, I only evaluate the iBeacon tech based on [Apple's sample code demo, Airlocated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AirLocate/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013430-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Therefore, I only implement two methods, including `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` in the file `APLAppDelegate.m` as bellow:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Entered region: %@", region);
    [self sendLocalNotificationForBeaconRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Exited region: %@", region);
}
```

Bellow steps have been tried, but no effect.

- Reset iPhone5/iPhone4s with iOS7.1
- Configure the background mode and *.plist as bellow:

> 1. in project info or info.plist -->
>           Custom IOS Target Properties -->
>                      . add "Required background modes"
>                      . in this add two items -->
>                                  ."App shares data using CoreBluetooth"
>                                  ."App registers for location updates"
> 2. in project Capability -->
>           There is Background Modes
>                     . check "Loaction update"
>                     . check "Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory"
>                     . check "uses bluetooth LE accessories"

- Authorize the application to access the device location.

So, could anyone give me some suggestion on it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try add region.notifyOnEntry = YES; region.notifyOnExit = YES; after you create CLBeaconRegion.

Comment: thanks for your prompt feedback, it'll update status soon after try it.

Comment: Greg, seems no effect after specify the parameter as "region.notifyOnEntry = YES; region.notifyOnExit = YES "

Comment: Thanks all the same, Greg. It's the first time I raise a question and you was the first person give me reply on stackoverflow.com. ^_^^_^^_^^_^^_^^_^ Time to leave office for me. Bey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `startRangingBeaconsInRegion` method after `startMonitoringForRegion` and try again

`[_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:demoRegion];` // demoRegion - region you have created

Comment: Alex, thanks for your suggestion. I will add the result after try it. BTW, the ranging API works normally within the previous verification.

Comment: WOW!!!!!!!!!! The monitoring API works as expectation by your suggestion. Thank you very much!^_^^_^^_^^_^^_^^_^^_^^_^^_^ Why do you know that????? I have seen the relative description that your have pointed out in the apple help document ????

Comment: Yeah, just got the explanation on why to add startRangingBeaconsInRegion method after startMonitoringForRegion in David G.Young's note in http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html.