# didEnterRegion()/didExitRegion() never fired while application in the background or device locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

It's a further problem based on the question in [iBeacon Bluetooth didEnterRegion and didExitRegion methods are never fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756019/ibeacon-bluetooth-didenterregion-and-didexitregion-methods-are-never-fired) which have been solved.

In detail, the method of didEnterRegion and didExitRegion are **never fired while the beacon application in the background or the device locked**. In addition, these two methods could be **triggered normally while the beacon application in the front**.

My application is **based on the apple demo "Airlocated** (sample code, provided by apple inc)" in the bellow link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AirLocate/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013430-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2. I hardly modify any code **except adding some code** as bellow:

in file "APLAppDelegate.m"

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Entered region: %@", region);

    [self sendLocalNotificationForBeaconRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Exited region: %@", region);
}
```

in file APLMonitoringViewcontroller.m

```
- (void)updateMonitoredRegion
{
...

            [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
            [self.locationManager startRangeingForRegion:region];
...
}
```

Complement a bit. I have tried the bellow methods:

- Set "Location updates" Background Mode to YES
- specify notifyOnExit and notifyOnEntry as true
- reboot iPhone4s with iOS 7.1.2

Could anyone give me some suggestions on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How long are you waiting for background detections?  Under some circumstances, this can take up to 15 minutes.  [See here for details.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html)

As described in that article, you do not need to set location updates Background Mode to YES, nor do you need to specify notifyOnExit and notifyOnEntry as true.

Comment: Sorry for late response due to the network problem. Thanks for your reminding on the entering and exiting beacon region is not respective especially while the application is in background. I gets lost of relative points in your article.

Comment: to optimize the beacon region changes notification, it's seems there is no effective work-around to solve the latency problem while the iBeacon application in the background rather than foreground. is it?

Comment: Hello David. Coming back to this in 2021, can you say if it still takes up to 15 minutes for background detections? And if it is so slow on average also or it is rare worst case scenario?

Comment: This is a rare worst-case scenario.  Newer iPhones have Bluetooth chips with a dozen or more hardware filters for fast detections.  If multiple apps scan for Bluetooth and use all these slots, the next app to do so will get slow detections.  This is usually a problem only on development devices.